# ViewController vs. without Nib file

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiview, nib, conceptual

When I create a `UIViewController` in Xcode I can decide to add a nib file. Assuming I don't add the nib file at this time. Can I simple add a nib file later and give it the same name as the ViewController?

I am asking this because I currently have a tableview with a certain background color. However, when the view is displayed it looks like the generic `UITableView` is used instead.

So it is like my nib file is ignored, in fact, when I delete the nib file, it still works the same, but without the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out what my nib file was ignored. The problem was that I did not instantiate my ViewController myself bug I defined it in IB by adding a `NSObject` to my storyboard and setting its class to my class.

However, like this the object is simply `alloc] init]`'ed but to load the nib, it has to be allocated like this:

```
    self.myVC = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

As soon as I do this the nib is loaded and I can configure my `UITableView` in Xcode. Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain you can. You'll have to edit the class of the File's Owner in that nib file, so that it gets linked with your custom `UIViewController` class.